# Multi - Winsock send data

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem with MSWinsock, the problem is:
I have a VB.NET application with multi winsock controls, all of them works at the same time, but when all of them send data (Obj.Senddata(data)), the data of some of them not reveived by the other side.

What is the problem?

Comment: Are you sure you are not using VB6 instead of VB.NET?

Comment: I'm using VB.NET 2003

Comment: If you are using .NET you should be using either the Socket class or the TcpClient class.  The Winsock control is primarily for VB6.

Comment: Yes, but where is the problem doing that in VB.NET?

Comment: You are going to have to post both the code that sends the data, and the code that receives it, as the problem could be on either side.  I know it can be drag, it is pretty much how this site works...

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Function PublishTemplateToTerminal()

    lblStatus.Text = "Publish in progress..."

    Dim DataToSend As String

    DataToSend = CType(Me.ParentForm, PublishTemplate).ALFullTemplateDetails.Item(Index)
    Index += 1
    Winsock.SendData(DataToSend)
    Application.DoEvents()

End Function

Private Sub Winsock_DataArrival(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As AxMSWinsockLib.DMSWinsockControlEvents_DataArrivalEvent) Handles Winsock.DataArrival

    Dim Msg As String = ""

    Winsock.GetData(Msg)
    ReceivedData &= Msg

    If ReceivedData.StartsWith("#999#") = True And ReceivedData.EndsWith("#END#") = True Then

         ReceivedData = ReceivedData.Substring(5)
        ReceivedData = ReceivedData.Substring(0, ReceivedData.Length - 5)

        If ReceivedData.StartsWith("ERROR") = True Then

            Winsock.Close()

            lblStatus.Text = "Error publish template to terminal!"
            lblStatus.BackColor = Color.Red

        End If

        If ReceivedData.StartsWith("DONE") = True Then

            ProgressBar.Value += 1

            If Index < CType(Me.ParentForm, PublishTemplate).ALFullTemplateDetails.Count Then

                Dim DataToSend As String
                DataToSend = CType(Me.ParentForm, PublishTemplate).ALFullTemplateDetails.Item(Index)
                Index += 1

                Winsock.SendData(DataToSend)
                Application.DoEvents()

            Else

                Winsock.Close()

                lblStatus.Text = "Publish Complete"
                lblStatus.BackColor = Color.Green

            End If

        End If

        ReceivedData = ""

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Here I send the data in the function: PublishTemplateToTerminal, And depends on the response I send the rest of data. This code is in a user control. When adding one user control to the form, everything goes well, but when adding more than one user control, the problem occures. Each user control connects to different client.